# UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, pygame

```
MAX_HEIGHT = 640
MAX_WIDTH = 320
DISPLAY = (MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT)
BACKGROUND_COLOR = '#2F4F4F'

ship = Spaceship(160, 0)
left = False
right = False


def main():
    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Piu")
    bg = pygame.Surface((MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT))
    bg.fill(Color(BACKGROUND_COLOR))

    while 1:
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == 'QUIT':
                raise SystemExit("QUIT")

            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = True

            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = False

        screen.blit(bg, (0,0))
        pygame.display.update()
        ship.update(left,right)
        ship.draw(screen)
```

Почему в `ship.update(left,right)` выпадает

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'left' referenced before assignment

Comment: `left` у вас вроде не глобальная, в цикле при вызове `ship.update(left,right)` она скорее всего еще не определена (т.к. определена она только при нажатии клавиши), отсюда и ошибка. Т.е. в функции за пределами цикла явно определите left и right - должно помочь. Определить можно либо как вы уже определили за пределами функции, либо добавив в начале функции `global left; global right`

Comment: не глобальная сейчас, т.к. у вас есть присваивание для этих переменных, но отсутствует явное указание на то, что эти переменные глобальные. Насколько помню, такое разрешено только для чтения

Comment: @BOPOH Почему не в отдельный ответ? Даже по объёму уже достаточно для ответа.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev, вы мою предвыборную программу видно не читали ) К тому же я злостный нарушитель, олицетворение [чистого зла](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/2321/5079) В общем мне так проще, в комментах написал как написал и не паришься, а над ответом еще подумать надо, чтобы нормально выглядело. Не мое это в общем ))

Comment: @BOPOH Читал, но ещё раз напоминаю. Тот же самый текст можно опубликовывать и в виде ответа, хуже это не сделает.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [UnboundLocalError: local variable 'L' referenced before assignment Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21456739/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С `pygamne` я не сталкивался но исключение сообщает, что вы обращаетесь к переменной `left` до ее создания.
Скорее всего проблема с областями видимости. Когда вы создаете переменную  в модуле, вы заносите ее в словарь глобальных переменных, который можно посмотреть функцией `globals()`
То же самое с локальными переменными, внутри функции их можно посмотреть функцией `locals()`
Соответственно переменные с одинаковыми именам из глобальной области видимости и локальной будут разные
Чтобы изменять глобальную переменную из функции можно использовать `global`
`global your_variable` Но это плохая практика и лучше попробовать добавить ваши переменные внутрь функции.